# How can I merge two commits in git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I recently pushed a commit to my git remote repository, and now I'm going to commit another change.

Is there a way I can merge these commits into a single commit?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [interactive rebasing](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history).

Run the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

You'll see something like this, in the editor that opens:

```
pick 3e7ee36 Older commit message
pick fa20af3 Newer commit message

# Rebase 8db7e8b..fa20af3 onto 8db7e8b
# ...
```

`fixup` or `squash` the newer commit, i.e., replace the `pick` in the newer commit to `fixup` and save and quit the file. This will merge the 2 commits keeping the older message:

```
pick 3e7ee36 Older commit message
fixup fa20af3 Newer commit message

# Rebase 8db7e8b..fa20af3 onto 8db7e8b
# ...
```

Comment: I have already pushed the previous commit. Is that going to be a problem and where should I give the "git rebase -i HEAD~2" In master or bugfix branch im currently working.

Comment: `git push --force` should fix that for you.

Comment: where should I give the "git rebase -i HEAD~2" In master or bugfix branch im currently working?

Comment: Whichever branch the 2 commits are present in.

Comment: Thanks for the help, im able to merge the two commits and the pull request updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the `rebase` command

```
$ git init
$ touch readme
$ git add readme
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
[master (root-commit) 6dde006] Initial Commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 readme
$ touch a
$ touch b
$ git add a
$ git commit -m "First commit"
[master 74296cb] First commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
$ git add b
$ git commit -m "Second commit" --squash=HEAD
[master 9ba46ab] squash! First commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 b
$ git rebase HEAD~2 -i
```

Simple save and close the editor of rebasing, then git will ask you for a new message for the merged commit, you can edit it, if you want.

```
[detached HEAD f855a0f] First commit
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
$ git log --oneline
cf855a0f First commitinsertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
6dde006 Initial Commit
```

If you pushed the first commit you can update the remote branch with the `force` option, but be carefull, if someone has already pulled your changes they will have tons of problems when you forcible push your changes:

```
git push origin master --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from the command line?

1).
If you have just made commit `A` to branch `my-branch` and pushed it up, and you do some work, you can use:

`git add -A` followed by `git commit --amend` which will add your changes to that commit you have already pushed. Then use `git push -f origin my-branch`

2).
If you have pushed commit `A` and then already committed `B` to branch `my-branch` then you can do the following:

`git rebase --soft HEAD~` which will undo commit `B` and then use `git commit --amend` to add the changes into commit `A` and then as above use `git push -f origin my-branch`